# How to integrate selenium and ZAP

Tags: java, selenium, security, zap, zapproxy

I am planning to automate security testing for a web application.
I have the selenium code which is developed using JAVA language, now I need to integrate with ZAP.

Kindly help me how to integrate these two and generate the reports for the same.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure Selenium to use Zap as a [proxy](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/proxy.html). Take a look [here](https://github.com/Soluto/webdriverio-zap-proxy) for a full solution using WebDriver.io, which is a tiny JS wrapper around selenium. It should give you a high level overview of how to build and run such a solution in the CI. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I am using Java Language. Can you please suggest how to achieve it.

Comment: You can take a look at this [link](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/proxy.html) which I also posted in my answer - it showed how to configure selenium to use a proxy. Except that, the rest could be the same IMO